# I need to know if it is the ketuvah of my parents, what does it say? Dates, names, etc

Tags: names, marriage, translation, eretz-yisrael, ketubah

I have to travel to Israel and they ask me for a marriage certificate from my parents or grandparents I have this document but I don't know if it is and I don't have anyone who can translate it for me, I am from Latin America and I am not close to a Jewish community, I appreciate the help! !

[image]

Comment: By travel to Israel you mean make aliyah? Anyone can travel to Israel regardless of parents' marriage documents

Comment: Were your parents married April 12, 1956? It looks like it says your parents are Moshe Harari and Sarah? I can't make out the location but this looks like a kesubah from the state of Israel

Comment: that's right they got married in 1956 my mother sara is guer, this was in argentina they moved

Comment: says if the case the rab. Israel erlichl?

Comment: It's low-res but given what you've said, the location field looks like it could very well be "Buenos Aires." Though that's the Seal of the State of Israel in yellow in the background. And yes you're in luck, it's definitely a Sephardic ketubah. (It writes more of the optional agreement/conditions about the couple into the text itself; Ashkenazim tended to make that a separate document.) I assume it has signatures on the bottom? People here could translate the entire form, but the point is it's a ketubah.

Comment: If you have signatures, thank you very much!

Comment: If someone could translate all the text, it would be very helpful for me! my parents passed away when i was a child

Comment: Ignacio vivo en Jerusalen, mi correo sale en mi perfil, mandáme un mensajito antes de venir ;)

Comment: The stuff already in the form looks roughly like this, with added bits: https://www.modernketubah.com/ketubah_translation.php -- none of that is specific to your parents. The only parts specific to them are what's filled in by hand: the date "1st of Iyyar, 5716" = Thu, 12 April 1956 (or 11 April after dark); the location -- looks like Buenos Aires; the groom's name - Moshe son of Mordechai Harary; the bride's name -- Sarah daughter of Abraham [can't make out her last name]; oh and the rabbi filled in something about paying optional extra silver -- which is normal.

Comment: If there are two witnesses' signatures on the bottom (and there should be), that may give you information about the witnesses. Very often you'll see the handwriting of one witness match the writing filling in the blanks. It was almost certainly the officiating rabbi who filled in the form, so you may find his name from the witness line. (When there weren't a lot of Orthodox Jews at the wedding, very often the rabbi served as a ketubah witness too.)